# Why do I get a syntax error when trying to put an if statement in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I need to insert different data in the database using a trigger, depending on the previously done update on a table, though I keep on getting a syntax error for some reason. I checked out a lot of similar questions to mine, but still my code seems fine.

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_history
AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF OLD.amount - NEW.amount > OLD.amount THEN
    INSERT INTO product_history (amount_of_new_products, product_id, user_id, updated_on, type_of_change)
    VALUES ((NEW.amount - OLD.amount), NEW.id, NEW.user_id, now(), 'order');
ELSE
    INSERT INTO product_history (amount_of_new_products, product_id, user_id, updated_on, type_of_change)
    VALUES ((NEW.amount - OLD.amount), NEW.id, NEW.user_id, now(), 'update');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an END IF.

Indent your code, so you can spot it easily.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_history
AFTER UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.amount - NEW.amount > OLD.amount THEN
        INSERT INTO product_history (amount_of_new_products, product_id, user_id, updated_on, type_of_change)
        VALUES ((NEW.amount - OLD.amount), NEW.id, NEW.user_id, now(), 'order');
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO product_history (amount_of_new_products, product_id, user_id, updated_on, type_of_change)
        VALUES ((NEW.amount - OLD.amount), NEW.id, NEW.user_id, now(), 'update');
    ENd IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```